# Add infinite scrolling in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, infinite-scroll

I'm new in flutter. I want to add infinite scrolling in my listview. I have no idea how to add in it with the api in diferrent dart file. I have this in my model class file. I create the api in my model class file.

```
  Future<List<RestaurantReview>> filterReview(int restaurantId,
      {String? query = "", int? offset = null, int? page = null}) async {
    var response = await httpSer
        .get('restaurant/review/$restaurantId/filter?filter=$query&offset=$offset&page=$page');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      reviewList = restaurantReviewlistFromJson(response.body);

      if (reviewList.isNotEmpty) {
        //review = reviewList.where((filterReview) => filterReview.userId == userdetails.id).first;
        review = reviewList.firstWhere(
            (filterReview) => filterReview.userId == userdetails.id,
            orElse: () => review = reviewList.firstWhere(
                (filterReview) => filterReview.restaurantId == restaurantId));
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }
    return reviewList;
  }
```

this is my showComment widget in another dart file which I want to add infinite scrolling in it.

```
  Widget showComment(BuildContext context, List<dynamic> data) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.h),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 80.h,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${data[index].userFullName}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12.h,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    RatingBar(
                      ignoreGestures: true,
                      initialRating: data[index].rating,
                      allowHalfRating: false,
                      direction: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemSize: 15,
                      ratingWidget: RatingWidget(
                        full: Icon(Icons.star_rounded, color: Colors.yellow),
                        half:
                            Icon(Icons.star_half_rounded, color: Colors.yellow),
                        empty: Icon(Icons.star_border_rounded,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4.h),
                Text(
                  DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(data[index].createdDate),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.h, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.h),
                Text(
                  "${data[index].comment ?? ''}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.h,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

if there is offset you dont actually need page. you could use limit (optional) instead.

so, first of all, you need to only load x data (lets suppose 10) to the page, and render it. then as you scroll, you can detect the scroll offset and fetch more data. here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfiniteScrollExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const InfiniteScrollExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<InfiniteScrollExample> createState() => _InfiniteScrollExampleState();
}

class _InfiniteScrollExampleState extends State<InfiniteScrollExample> {
  late final ScrollController _controller;
  int page = 0;
  List<dynamic> data = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(index.toString()),
      itemCount: data.length,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _loadMoreData() async {
    page++;
    final res = await filterReview(*your params*, page);
    data = [...data, ...res];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final hasReachedEnd = _controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent && !_controller.position.outOfRange;
      if(!hasReachedEnd) return;
      _loadMoreData();
    });
  }
}
```